# How to separate with commas an unpacked list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, unpack, fuzzywuzzy

Unpacking the resulting list of tuples into a comma-separated values.

Using FuzzyWuzzy, I am comparing 2 files and want to output the results into a 3rd file.

Building out from this SO question: 
[Python: Keepning only the outerloop max result when comparing string similarity of two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56414872/python-keepning-only-the-outerloop-max-result-when-comparing-string-similarity/56417682#56417682)

The output is:

```
[('Item_number', ('Item number', 91)), ('Item', ('Item name', 62))]
```

Using this unpack method,I was able to separate the values:

```
for i in mapper:
    print(*[i[0]],*[*i[1]])
```

Output:

```
Item_number Item number 91
Item Item name 62
```

Now, here is where I fall short. I am looking for the individual values to be comma-separated in order to be saved to a CSV file.

I tested many other solutions such as itertools but without success such as:

```
[('I', 't', 'e', 'm', '_', 'n', 'u', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'r', 'Item number', 91), ('I', 't', 'e', 'm', 'Item name', 62)]
```

Expected output:

```
Item_number, Item number, 91
Item, Item name, 62
```

Note: I am not looking for itertool specific solution but rather a solution that make sense.

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question? Minimal, working example and knowledege, what you got and you expected would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try unpacking it to the individual components, then printing them with commas in between:

```py
for (i,(j,k)) in mapper:
    print(i,j,k, sep=',')
```

(would probably be better to give `i`, `j`, and `k` meaningful names, based on what the values actaully are...)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension, extending the values from the second tuples using [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), and then write the list to csv (check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list) on how to create a csv file from a list):

```
l = [('Item_number', ('Item number', 91)), ('Item', ('Item name', 62))]

[[i, *j] for i, j in l]
# [['Item_number', 'Item number', 91], ['Item', 'Item name', 62]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your existing code, you can use such a solution:

```
mapper = [('Item_number', ('Item number', 91)), ('Item', ('Item name', 62))]
for i in mapper:
    print(', '.join(map(str, (*[i[0]],*[*i[1]]))))
Item_number, Item number, 91
Item, Item name, 62
```

Comment: I learn from you the proper syntax for using ', '.join(map(str()))  in that specific case. Most certainly, this will be handy moving forward. Thx